# Python script auto close

Tags: python, timer, serial-port

I finally got code to print details from serial port without empty lines, but I dont know how can I make this script auto end work.

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from serial import Serial

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, 7, 'E', 1)

while True:
    # Read a line and convert it from b'xxx\r\n' to xxx
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]
    print line
```

and now I would like to open this script - print 2-3 seconds and automaticly close script. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `time` module:

```
from serial import Serial
import sys,time
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, 7, 'E', 1)

t1 = time.time()
while time.time() - t1 <= 3:
    # Read a line and convert it from b'xxx\r\n' to xxx
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]
    print line
sys.exit()     #exit script
```

**help** on `time.time`:

```
>>> time.time?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function time>
Docstring:
time() -> floating point number

Return the current time in seconds since the Epoch.
Fractions of a second may be present if the system clock provides them.
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules to consider: time & sys

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from serial import Serial
import time
import sys

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, 7, 'E', 1)
num_sleep = 0
seconds_to_sleep = 3
while True:
    if (num_sleep == seconds_to_sleep):
        break
    # Read a line and convert it from b'xxx\r\n' to xxx
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]
    print line
    time.sleep(1)
    num_sleep += 1
sys.exit()
```